# devise rails application redirecting to users/sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

all - 
New to rails and web development. I started a new rails application and am using Devise. Whenever I hit Log In on the users/sign_in page, the page just refreshes.

Here is my terminal log after clicking Log In. It's showing the POST, I'm not sure why it's ultimately rendering devise/sessions/new.html....:

```
    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2017-10-02 09:19:20 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ot4EJmxLvXrPpa6WYyqCXHxAUT3DcHimrIfw8HGyu5j7yuXvWArEkWzx59Dj3GZrlVDpgS/xSgXFSIt+mQqQnw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"bob@good.company", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in!"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["email", "bob@good.company"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 162ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2017-10-02 09:19:21 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 43.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'charges/create'
  devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'welcome/about'
  resources :wikis
  resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

and my User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
  has_many :wikis

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  enum role: [:standard, :admin, :premium]
  after_initialize { self.role ||= :standard }

end
```

Thank you for any direction and please let me know if I can provide any more details / code samples etc.

Comment: May seem like an obvious/dumb question, but are you entering a valid username+password? Does this user exist in your database?

Comment: @TomLord yesterday I cleared my db and seeded it using the Faker gem. Could this have something to do with it? When I go to the /sign_up page and enter a new username and password it sends me straight to localhost:3000. From there, if I type in /users/edit (for example) it redirects me right back to /sign_up.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you seeded the data; the only important question is: Does the user `"bob@good.company"` exist, and did you enter the correct password? If not, then this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about `/users/edit`. This route does not exist, so (by default) you should see a 404 page -- unless you have configured "not found" to respond with a `401` error, or redirect to the login page.

Comment: I don't think the passwords are saving to the db, because when I go to the console and try to call for the password of a sample User it returns this ------- NoMethodError: undefined method `password' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ff3f286aba8>

Comment: That's not how passwords work. They are **encrypted**. You cannot read them back as plain text. If it were possible to do this, it would be a *huge* security issue.

Comment: Check that the user exists (or create one if they don't), and **set** the password through the console. Then try to log in as them.

Comment: @TomLord thanks for your help. I got it sorted with your tips. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please update this user password from console

this happened because of you only provided only password attribute, you skipped password_confirmation attribute

eg User.where(email: "Youremail@email.com").update(password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")